# VBA array adding

Tags: vba, excel, macros

```
 For j = 1 To 8
 Sheet5.Cells(j + 1, 2) = 480
 Next
 t = 0
 c = 0
     For j = LBound(arrayTime) + 1 To UBound(arrayTime)
        MsgBox "j " & j
       'MsgBox (t)
        numMins = Sheet5.Cells((j + 1) - (8 * c), 2) - arrayTime(j)
        If numMins < 0 Then
        t = t + 1
        ReDim Preserve arrayTime(numrows - 1 + t)
        arrayTime(numrows - 1 + t) = arrayTime(j)
        MsgBox (arrayTime(numrows - 1 + t))
        Else
        Sheet5.Cells((j + 1) - (8 * c), 2) = numMins
        End If
        If j = 8 * (c + 1) Then
        c = c + 1
        End If
        MsgBox ("end " & t)
    Next
```

Im trying to add an value to arrayTime if  the condition is true. I successfully added it but the for loop will not re-dimension to loop through the added element. The array originally contains 12 elements then I add a 13th but the loop does to recognize the 13th element and only loops 12 times. Any suggestions on how to get the for loop to loop 13 times?

Comment: Why another iteration, just do what's inside the `if` statement?? Edit: uh, the for loop. Guessing just `numMins = Sheet5.Cells((j + 1) - (8 * c), 2) - arrayTime(j)`?

Comment: Once in the loop you can not change the ending number, it becomes static.  You will need to change to some form of Do Loop.

Comment: because I need to subtract the last element of the array from a number in the cell. I want it to loop until the if statement is never true

Comment: So put `numMins = Sheet5.Cells((j + 1) - (8 * c), 2) - arrayTime(j)` after `arrayTime(numrows - 1 + t) = arrayTime(j)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yea, I dont want to subtract from that cell because it is less than 0

Comment: how would you change my for loop to a do loop to change dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a loop counter, say `i`, and set it to `LBound(arrayTime) + 1` then use a `Do Until (i = UBound(arrayTime))`.  This forces VBA to recalculate the upper bound before each loop.

Comment: Probably dumb question but do I put i under the do until loop or within it?

Comment: this did not change the upperbound

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Set i to the initial value before the do loop.  You have to increment i within the loop (`i = i + 1`).